# Inserting elements 1-1000 in an Array (VB.NET Console Application)

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, integer

To create an array having values 1 to 1000 and repeat  till a total of 1000000 elements are reached.

Comment: Is this a task to someone or you got a question?

Comment: This is not a place where people do homework for you.  You need to put forth some effort and ask a specific question when you run into problems.

Comment: I know that Myers. You don't have to tell me about what this site is used for. It is a task in my project where I'm stuck and needed help.

Comment: @AlanMathew, if you knew how this site worked, you'd know you need to show some effort. What have you tried so far? Do you have any code that you have tried and didn't work? What went wrong? Also, VB.NET is not VBA, and, as you obviously know, you shold use only the proper tags.

Comment: @AlanMathew Sorry.. realized just now that this is vb.net. please see the updated answer

Comment: This is my first post, so still learning. Yeah the tags are wrong and haven't posted my effort too.

Comment: You can edit your question to include the relevant code part. Don't forget to indicate the error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want but I am not sure why one would want to do that. If you tell what your final goal is, we can certainly come up with a better way.

```
Dim tba = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
Dim final = tba.ToList()
For Each x As Integer In Enumerable.Range(1, (1000000 / 1000) - 1)
    final.AddRange(tba)
Next
'final is your result
```

Comment: Basically I wanted to form an array with the values (1,2.......1000,1,2.....1000,.................,1,2.......1000) for a total of 1,000,000 elements.

Comment: @vacip coz I posted c# code accidentally, that's what I guess.

Comment: Yeah would you guys please help to do on vb.net

Comment: @AlanMathew I said I've updated the answer.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ I tried running it, but I am getting the following error. System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

Comment: @AlanMathew Sorry again, forgot to delete the semicolons from c#. Now I'm sure it would run

Comment: I removed the semi colon already, but still im getting the same error. I included Console.WriteLine(final) to print the array but it failed.

Comment: @AlanMathew This works perfectly fine. I think you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: That's your fault, `Console.WriteLine(final)` will print the tostring representation of the object. If you want to print it in a readable format, you can use this : `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", final))`.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ sorry to interrupt, but was there any issue with my solution just now?

Comment: @Ian no... i was just looking at your profile and you have so much reputation and earned so many bounties... I was impressed :) Not sure why you deleted that answer though...

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ No, I thought just now I made a mistake but I did not notice. Then you by friendliness is about to tell me that... :) Thus I deleted my answer to confirm. Seems like I got it wrong. Haha... You mean < 10k rep and 7 bounties? Not sure what should I say about that. But maybe it is because I am quite active these 2 months. That's it... :)